# How does an irreducible polynomial of prime power order split over an extension of prime power degree

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, fields

I asked this question in a similar form on math.se  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288297/towers-of-perfect-fields-of-mostly-order-pt), where it has been unanswered for a little over a week some work on it can be found there. The motivation for this question was another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286655/number-fields-with-all-degrees-equal-to-a-power-of-three) asked on math.se.

Fix a prime $p$ and $L$ a number field. Let $f(t) \in L[t]$ be irreducible such that $\deg f(t)=p^{j}$ and $L \subset K$ a field extension of degree $p^k$. What can we say about how $f(t)$ factors over $K[t]$? In particular is it true that $f(t)$ takes a root or has an irreducible factor of order $p^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: Yes.  Just think about the degrees $[L(c):L]$ and $[K(c):K]$ where $f(c)=0$.  You don't need the hypothesis $[L:K]=p^k$.

Comment: @Michael, I'm not quite sure what you're getting at $[K(c):K]$ is not a prime power for ever root. Consider $L=\mathbb Q$, $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[9]{2})$ and $x^{27}-2=(x^3 - \sqrt[9]{2})(x^6 + \sqrt[9]{2}x^3 + \sqrt[9]{2}^2)(x^{18} + (\sqrt[9]{2})^3x^9 + (\sqrt[9]{2})^6)$ over $K[x]$.


Comment: You're right, I had in mind the case that $K/L$ is Galois.  Your question is equivalent to the following: if $G$ is a transitive subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{p^n}$, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of $p$-power index, then must $H$ have an orbit of $p$-power size?  There are probably group theorists who can answer this immediately.

To see this equivalence, let $G$ be the Galois group of $f(t)$ over $L$, and let $H$ be the Galois group of $f(t)$ over $K$.  Writing $M$ for the splitting field of $f(t)$ over $L$, it follows that $H$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of $M/(M\cap K)$.

Comment: @Michael, Yes. I agree. I was working with something like that but I didn't think to use the the last correspondence. So I couldn't get the problem to phrase nicely in group theoretic terms. 

Comment: The answer to your question is no.  Let $f(t)\in L[t]$ be any degree-$7$ polynomial whose Galois group $G$ is the simple group of order $168$.  Then $G$ contains two conjugacy classes of index-$7$ subgroups.  All groups in one of these conjugacy classes have a fixed point, but the groups in the other class have orbits of sizes 3 and 4.  So if $K$ is the subfield of the splitting field of $f$ fixed by one of these index-$7$ subgroups of $G$ from the second class, then $f(t)$ factors in $K[t]$ into irreducibles of degrees $3$ and $4$.

Comment: To see $3+4$ easily, note that $G \cong GL_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$. One index $7$ subgroup is the stabilizer of a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, the other is the stabilizer of a hyperplane. If we use the first group to define the map $G \to S_7$, and take orbits for the other, then we get two orbits: the $3$ nonzero vectors in the hyperplane and the $4$ nonzero vectors out of it.

Comment: I'm curious how common the group-theoretic counterexamples will be: for instance, do there exist counterexamples for all but finitely many prime powers $p^n$?

Comment: @Mike: There are infinitely many primes $p$ for which there is no counterexample of degree $p$: By Burnside a transitive group $G$ of degree $p$ is as subgroup of $AGL(1,p)$, or it is doubly transitive. In the first case, any subgroup of index $p$ fixes a point. As to the second case, there are infinitely many $p$ such that $G=A_p$ or $S_p$. (Follows from the classification of the $2$-transitive groups.) However, in $A_p$ or $S_p$, a subgroup of index $p$ fixes a point. Actually, one can show that all counterexamples of prime degree come from $PSL(n,q)\le G\le P\Gamma L(n,q)$ for $n\ge3$ ...

Comment: ... with $p=(q^n-1)/(q-1)$, or $G=PSL(2,11)$ with $p=11$.

Comment: @Peter: I was just writing a similar comment.  Will the original assertion be true for polynomials of prime degree as long as the degree isn't 7, 11, or 31?

Comment: @Mike: No, whenever $p=(q^n-1)/(q-1)$ is a prime for $n\ge3$ (as it happens for Mersenne primes), you have an example like your example (for the same reason as in David's comment). As any finite group is a Galois group over *some* number field, there isn't a field theoretic obstruction.

Comment: Is there a reason why $L$ is the ground field, and $K$ the extension? Got me confused for a second... (-;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just for concreteness, here's an explicit counterexample along the lines of my comment.  Let $L=\mathbb{Q}$ and let $f(t)=t^7 - 7t+3$ and $g(t)=t^7-14t^4+42t^2-21t-9$.  Then $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are irreducible in $L[t]$.  Now let $K=\mathbb{Q}(c)$ where $g(c)=0$, so $[K:L]=7$.  Then $f(t)$ factors in $K[t]$ into irreducibles of degrees $3$ and $4$.  For instance, this can be verified using the following Magma code, which can be used on the [free Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc):

```
_<t>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals());
f:=t^7-7*t+3;
g:=t^7-14*t^4+42*t^2-21*t-9;
IsIrreducible(f);
K<c>:=NumberField(g);
_<x>:=PolynomialRing(K);
Factorization(Evaluate(f,x));
```